# How can I fit electric outlets on opposite sides of a 2x4 wall?

Tags: electrical, wiring, receptacle

How do you install electric outlets on both sides of a 2"x4" interior wall to meet code?  The back of each box (and wires entering box) is very close (less than 1/2") to the front of the other side of the wall.  Is there code on how to do this?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Where are you located?

Answer (score 2):

I'd use 4x4 boxes that are 1-1/2" deep with single gang raised mud rings.  These will give you plenty of room inside.

Feeding through the backs of the boxes with a nipple sounds easy but will turn out to be a pain.  Better to just feed bottom to bottom with a short romex jumper.

Comment: Any reason you don't use 120mm boxes instead of 100mm for this?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel - no, no reason, 4x4 is just my default box, do you prefer the 411?

Comment: I'd use a 5" or larger even if you could get them in such a shallow depth -- you can never have enough box space ;)

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel it's fine to do, but  I don't generally stock 120mm boxes (4-11/16") that are shallow enough.  When I use them I am all about the cubic inches, so I buy deep 120s.

Comment: If I follow correctly, the "single gang raised mud ring" would stick out from the wall?

Comment: @freeman - it sticks out from the front face of the box - the face of the box is even with the stud, so the raised ring is necessary to get the mounting screws flush with the drywall .

Comment: Got it! 2 x 1.5" deep boxes = 3" which leaves a small gap between them when back-to-back in the wall. The mud rings get them to the surface and give a smidge more room for wiring.